# Binding nested control using MVVM pattern

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, mvvm

I have a problem with binding nested control with my MVVM pattern. This is my XAML code:

```
 <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding NotificationContacts}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <toolkit:Expander>
                        <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContactName}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                                <Image Source="Images/answer_ok.png" Grid.Column="1" Margin="15,0,15,0" Width="27" Height="27"></Image>
                            </Grid>
                        </toolkit:Expander.Header>
                        <toolkit:Expander.Content>
                            <ListBox Margin="30,10,0,10" ItemsSource="{Binding NotificationContacts.Messages">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageName}"></TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </toolkit:Expander.Content>
                    </toolkit:Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

The problem is, that the listbox control located in ExpanderControl Data Template is not being  data bound. 
Listbox control is populated by EntityCollection named 'Messages' which is contained in parent object 'NotificationContacts' that ItemsControl is databound with...

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: what does your viewmodel look like?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding NotificationContacts}">
  ......
   <ListBox Margin="30,10,0,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
  .....
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageName}"></TextBlock>
```

If I remember it right, when you are "inside" ItemContol, binding context is set to NotificationContacts. So use just "{Binding Messages}" could be fine.

And by the way, you are missing curly bracket on the line:

```
<ListBox Margin="30,10,0,10" ItemsSource="{Binding NotificationContacts.Messages">
```

Answer (score 0):

Call ItemsControl f.i. "ic" and use next binding in ListBox

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ic" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding NotificationContacts}">
     ...
     <ListBox Margin="30,10,0,10" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ic, Path=DataContext.Messages}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, your solution didn't work for me.... The listbox still isn't being populated by the data...

Comment: which class contains Messages property?